# XML error Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: xml

i'm working with XML and when i try to parse it I got error "Extra content at the end of the document"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SMS-InsRequest>
    <CLIENT from="Prime" pwd="bliss" user="bliss"/>
    <INSERT datacoding="0">
        <TO>055XXXXXXX</TO>
        <TO>055XXXXXXX</TO>
    </INSERT>
    <TEXT>1c sms bakcell</TEXT>
</SMS-InsRequest>
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: is it linked the fact that there are 2 "TO" tags?

Comment: This XML looks OK, "extra content" indicates there is something behind it in the file. The error could come from how you handle (eg download, convert) the file.